# The onClick event for all links on an XPage execute when the page is opened or refreshed

Tags: xpages

I have a simple XPage which contains links to .pdf files stored within the application. In the onClick event of each link I have code that updates a document in another application. My problem is that when I open the page containing the links, the onClick event for each link also executes. How do I prevent the onClick events from executing when the page opens?

Here's the code from the onClick event of one of the links on the page:

```
<xp:link escape="true" text="Complex Passwords" id="link1" 
value="/ComplexPasswords.pdf">
<xp:this.onclick><![CDATA[#{javascript:var dbc: NotesDatabase =    
session.getCurrentDatabase();
if (dbc != null) {
var dbnam1 = dbc.getFileName();
} else {
print("No current db found");
return("");
}

var server = session.getServerName();
var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(server, "PageHitC", false); 
if (db == null) {
print("No page hit db found");
return("");
} 
var myView:NotesView = db.getView("ByAppName");  
if (myView == null){
print("No page hit db found");
return("");
}
var nkey = "Complex Passwords";    //'build the key to see if there is
already a document for this page in the page hit db
var query = new java.util.Vector();
query.add(dbnam1);
query.add(nkey);

var myDoc:NotesDocument = myView.getDocumentByKey(query,true);
if (myDoc == null) {                                                  
//'if there's no document found, create a new one
var newdoc:NotesDocument = db.createDocument();
    newdoc.replaceItemValue("Form","HitCnt");
    newdoc.replaceItemValue("AppName", dbnam1);
    newdoc.replaceItemValue("SName", server);
    newdoc.replaceItemValue("HitPages", "Complex Passwords");
    newdoc.replaceItemValue("HitSummary",1);
var dt:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("Today 12");
dt.setNow();
    newdoc.replaceItemValue("CntStart", dt);
    newdoc.replaceItemValue("LastUpd", dt);
    newdoc.save();
}else
{                        //'otherwise update the existing document
var tmp = myDoc.getItemValueInteger("HitSummary");
tmp++;
myDoc.replaceItemValue("HitSummary",tmp);
myDoc.save();
}}]]></xp:this.onclick>
</xp:link>
```

Comment: Please update your post to show some example source code of those links and how they are made.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us the complete code for the component too (the xp:link control) so that we can see where your logic is triggered.

Comment: I have added the complete source code for the link.

Comment: You have added SSJS to the browser-side onClick event. See Pauls answer

Answer (score 2):

Chances are you've added SSJS to the standard browser-side onClick event. Bear in mind the onClick event is to run on the browser, so is intended to contain CSJS. Use of SSJS there is to be processed on the server to return a String which the browser can parse as (normal Client-Side) JavaScript and run when the button or link is clicked.

It's normal processing for all SSJS in an onClick event of links to be processed server-side and so run before your page run.

What you probably need to do instead is trigger a partial refresh and, in its eventHandler onClick, run your SSJS.